# Updating results from a mysql-connector fetchall

Tags: python, mysql-connector

I'm trying to select certain records from the civicrm_address table and update the geocode columns. I use fetchall to retrieve the rows then, within the same loop, I try to update with the results of the geocoder API, passing the civicrm_address.id value in the update_sql statement.

The rowcount after the attempted update and commit is always -1 so I am assuming it failed for some reason but I have yet to figure out why.

```
import geocoder
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  [redacted]
)


mycursor = mydb.cursor(dictionary=True)
update_cursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = """

    select
        a.id
        , street_address
        , city
        , abbreviation
    from
        civicrm_address a
        , civicrm_state_province b
    where
        location_type_id = 6
    and
        a.state_province_id = b.id
    and
        street_address is not null
    and
        city is not null
    limit 5

"""
mycursor.execute(sql)
rows = mycursor.fetchall()
print(mycursor.rowcount, "records selected")

for row in rows:
    address_id = int(row["id"])
    street_address = str(row["street_address"])
    city = str(row["city"])
    state = str(row["abbreviation"])

    myaddress = street_address + " " + city + ", " + state

    g = geocoder.arcgis(myaddress)
    d = g.json

    latitude = d["lat"]
    longitude = d["lng"]

    update_sql = """
    begin work;
    update
        civicrm_address
    set
        geo_code_1 = %s
        , geo_code_2 = %s
    where
        id = %s
    """
    var=(latitude, longitude, address_id)
    print(var)
    update_cursor.execute(update_sql, var, multi=True)
    mydb.commit()
    print(update_cursor.rowcount)

mycursor.close()
update_cursor.close()
mydb.close()
```

**Here is a simpler script**:

I have executed the update_sql statement directly in the MySQL workbench and it succeeds. It is not working from Python.

```
import geocoder
import mysql.connector

try:
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
[redacted]
    )

    mycursor = mydb.cursor(dictionary=True)
    update_cursor = mydb.cursor()

    update_sql = """
    begin work;
    update
        civicrm_address
    set
        geo_code_1 = 37.3445
        , geo_code_2 = -118.5366074
    where
        id = 65450;
    """
    update_cursor.execute(update_sql, multi=True)
    mydb.commit()
    print(update_cursor.rowcount, "row(s) were updated")

except mysql.connector.Error as error:
    print("Failed to update record to database: {}".format(error))
    mydb.rollback()

finally:
    # closing database connection.
    if (mydb.is_connected()):
        mydb.close()
```

Comment: The first query returns over 90,000 rows.  If it didn't, the geocoder call would fail.

Comment: Remove `begin work;` from `update_sql`.

Comment: Removing begin work has no effect

Comment: Try removing `multi=True`. It returns an iterator. It appears the [`UPDATE` is not performed unless the iterator is iterated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36166577/190597).

Answer (score 0):

I have it working now. I did remove the "begin work" statement but not the multi=True and it wouldn't work. Later I removed the multi=True statement and it works.