# mysql.connector does not execute insert into with multi flag in python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I've a little bit complex MySQL insertion, which sets some variables, joins some tables, aggregates values, then tries to insert into a table. This SQL `INSERT` command WORKS when I try to execute with DBeaver.

- When I try to run this SQL command without the insertion part, the mysql.connector with the same options handles it correctly, gives back the result set, which I can process (but I want to write back the results into a table)
- When I add the `INSERT INTO worklogs_aggregated SELECT Z.* FROM (...) Z` around the `SELECT` statement (except the `SET` part), the library can't execute it properly, and I don't really understand why.
  I don't get any error message. The execution finishes without any errors, but nothing appears in the table. If I copy the same command and try to execute it in DBeaver, it works perfectly.

My simplified Python code is similar to this:

```
import mysql.connector
import config as cfg

def rds_db_connect_for_multi_statement():

    token = aws_generate_db_auth_token()

    config = {
        'host': cfg.db_config['hostname'],
        'port': cfg.db_config['port'],
        'user': cfg.db_config['username'],
        'password': token,
        'database': cfg.db_config['database'],
        'ssl_ca': cfg.db_config['ca_path'],
        'charset': cfg.db_config['charset'],
        'raise_on_warnings': True
    }
    return mysql.connector.connect( **config )

if __name__== "__main__":

    connection = None
    cursor = None
    try:
        connection = rds_db_connect_for_multi_statement()
        cursor = connection.cursor(buffered=True)

        LONG_SQL_COMMAND=... # the SQL command from below
        cursor.execute(LONG_SQL_COMMAND, multi=True)

        connection.commit()

        cursor.close()
        connection.close()

    except Exception as e:
        if(cursor):
            cursor.close()
        elif(connection):
            connection.rollback()
            connection.close()
        else:
            raise(e)
```

This is working without the `INSERT INTO`:

```sql
SET 
  @row_number := 0, 
  @l_datum := '1900-01-01',
  @l_member_id := 0,  
  @l_project_sm_id := 0;

SELECT 
  datum, 
  member_id, 
  project_sm_id, 
  ts_email, 
  project_sm_name, 
  project_ts_project_name, 
  assigment_assigment_id, 
  assigment_projekt_id, 
  assigment_hr_contact_id, 
  assigment_user_id, 
  duration_hour 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      @row_number := CASE 
                          WHEN @l_datum = datum 
                           AND @l_member_id = member_id 
                           AND @l_project_sm_id = project_sm_id 
                          THEN @row_number + 1 
                          ELSE 1 
                     END AS project_order, 
      @l_datum := datum AS datum, 
      @l_member_id := member_id AS member_id, 
      @l_project_sm_id := project_sm_id AS project_sm_id, 
      ts_email AS ts_email, 
      project_sm_name AS project_sm_name, 
      project_ts_project_name AS project_ts_project_name, 
      assigment_assigment_id AS assigment_assigment_id, 
      assigment_projekt_id AS assigment_projekt_id, 
      assigment_hr_contact_id AS assigment_hr_contact_id, 
      assigment_user_id AS assigment_user_id, 
      duration_hour AS duration_hour 
    FROM 
      (
        SELECT 
          wrk.work_dt AS datum, 
          wrk.member_id AS member_id, 
          wrk.project_id AS project_sm_id, 
          Coalesce(
            Lower(emap.ts_email), 
            Lower(mem.email)
          ) AS ts_email, 
          prj.name AS project_sm_name, 
          map.ts_project_name AS project_ts_project_name, 
          asg.assignment_id AS assigment_assigment_id, 
          asg.projekt_id AS assigment_projekt_id, 
          asg.hr_contact_id AS assigment_hr_contact_id, 
          asg.user_id AS assigment_user_id, 
          Ceil(
            Sum(duration_min) / 60
          ) AS duration_hour 
        FROM 
          sm2ts.worklogs AS wrk 
          JOIN sm2ts.ref_projects AS prj ON prj.id = wrk.project_id 
          JOIN sm2ts.project_map AS map ON map.sm_id = wrk.project_id 
          LEFT JOIN sm2ts.ref_members AS mem ON mem.id = wrk.member_id 
          LEFT JOIN sm2ts.email_map AS emap ON Lower(emap.sm_email) = Lower(mem.email) 
          JOIN sm2ts.sf_assignments AS asg ON Lower(asg.email) = Coalesce(
            Lower(emap.ts_email), 
            Lower(mem.email)
          ) 
          AND Lower(asg.project_name) = Lower(map.ts_project_name) 
        WHERE 
          wrk.work_dt BETWEEN '2020-01-01' 
          AND '2020-02-06' 
          AND map.sm_org_id = '544411' 
        GROUP BY 
          wrk.member_id, 
          wrk.work_dt, 
          wrk.project_id, 
          map.sm_id, 
          Coalesce(
            Lower(emap.ts_email), 
            Lower(mem.email)
          ), 
          prj.name, 
          map.sm_name, 
          map.ts_project_name, 
          asg.assignment_id, 
          asg.projekt_id, 
          asg.hr_contact_id, 
          asg.user_id 
        ORDER BY 
          wrk.member_id, 
          wrk.work_dt, 
          wrk.project_id, 
          map.sm_id, 
          Coalesce(
            Lower(emap.ts_email), 
            Lower(mem.email)
          ), 
          prj.name, 
          map.sm_name, 
          map.ts_project_name, 
          asg.assignment_id, 
          asg.projekt_id, 
          asg.hr_contact_id, 
          asg.user_id
      ) X
  ) Y 
WHERE 
  Y.project_order = 1 
ORDER BY 
  datum, 
  member_id, 
  project_sm_id;
```

This is not working with the `INSERT INTO`:

```sql
SET 
  @row_number := 0, 
  @l_datum := '1900-01-01', 
  @l_member_id := 0, 
  @l_project_sm_id := 0;

INSERT INTO worklogs_aggregated 
SELECT Z.* 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      datum, 
      member_id, 
      project_sm_id, 
      ts_email, 
      project_sm_name, 
      project_ts_project_name, 
      assigment_assigment_id, 
      assigment_projekt_id, 
      assigment_hr_contact_id, 
      assigment_user_id, 
      duration_hour 
    FROM 
      (
        SELECT 
          @row_number := CASE 
                           WHEN @l_datum = datum 
                            AND @l_member_id = member_id 
                            AND @l_project_sm_id = project_sm_id 
                           THEN @row_number + 1 
                           ELSE 1 
                         END AS project_order, 
          @l_datum := datum AS datum, 
          @l_member_id := member_id AS member_id, 
          @l_project_sm_id := project_sm_id AS project_sm_id, 
          ts_email AS ts_email, 
          project_sm_name AS project_sm_name, 
          project_ts_project_name AS project_ts_project_name, 
          assigment_assigment_id AS assigment_assigment_id, 
          assigment_projekt_id AS assigment_projekt_id, 
          assigment_hr_contact_id AS assigment_hr_contact_id, 
          assigment_user_id AS assigment_user_id, 
          duration_hour AS duration_hour 
        FROM 
          (
            SELECT 
              wrk.work_dt AS datum, 
              wrk.member_id AS member_id, 
              wrk.project_id AS project_sm_id, 
              COALESCE(
                LOWER(emap.ts_email), 
                LOWER(mem.email)
              ) AS ts_email, 
              prj.name AS project_sm_name, 
              map.ts_project_name AS project_ts_project_name, 
              asg.ASSIGNMENT_ID AS assigment_assigment_id, 
              asg.PROJEKT_ID AS assigment_projekt_id, 
              asg.HR_CONTACT_ID AS assigment_hr_contact_id, 
              asg.USER_ID AS assigment_user_id, 
              CEIL(
                SUM(duration_min) / 60
              ) AS duration_hour 
            FROM 
              sm2ts.worklogs AS wrk 
              JOIN sm2ts.ref_projects AS prj ON prj.id = wrk.project_id 
              JOIN sm2ts.project_map AS map ON map.sm_id = wrk.project_id 
              LEFT JOIN sm2ts.ref_members AS mem ON mem.id = wrk.member_id 
              LEFT JOIN sm2ts.email_map AS emap ON LOWER(emap.sm_email) = LOWER(mem.email) 
              JOIN sm2ts.sf_assignments AS asg ON LOWER(asg.email) = COALESCE(
                LOWER(emap.ts_email), 
                LOWER(mem.email)
              ) 
              AND LOWER(asg.PROJECT_NAME) = LOWER(map.ts_project_name) 
            WHERE 
              wrk.work_dt BETWEEN '2020-01-01' 
              AND '2020-02-06' 
              AND map.sm_org_id = '544411' 
            GROUP BY 
              wrk.member_id, 
              wrk.work_dt, 
              wrk.project_id, 
              map.sm_id, 
              COALESCE(
                LOWER(emap.ts_email), 
                LOWER(mem.email)
              ), 
              prj.name, 
              map.sm_name, 
              map.ts_project_name, 
              asg.ASSIGNMENT_ID, 
              asg.PROJEKT_ID, 
              asg.HR_CONTACT_ID, 
              asg.USER_ID 
            ORDER BY 
              wrk.member_id, 
              wrk.work_dt, 
              wrk.project_id, 
              map.sm_id, 
              COALESCE(
                LOWER(emap.ts_email), 
                LOWER(mem.email)
              ), 
              prj.name, 
              map.sm_name, 
              map.ts_project_name, 
              asg.ASSIGNMENT_ID, 
              asg.PROJEKT_ID, 
              asg.HR_CONTACT_ID, 
              asg.USER_ID
          ) X
      ) Y 
    WHERE 
      Y.project_order = 1 
    ORDER BY 
      datum, 
      member_id, 
      project_sm_id
  ) Z;
```

- What causes the problem while executing the insertion from Python?
- Why I don't get any error while executing the same SQL command with DBeaver?
- How could I get the error message if no exception is thrown?

Comment: Your life would be so much easier if using MySQL 8 that supports [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) and mostly does away with `@` variables needs. Please advise which version you use: `SELECT version();`. Possibly the `SET` interferes with `INSERT` action.

Comment: See this answer which will make your question a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36166772/1422451

Comment: @Parfait I'm using an older version of MySQL, your query gives back this version number: 5.7.26

Comment: @Parfait Thank you for the idea, sadly this solution didn't solve my problem: `for _ in cursor.execute(LONG_SQL_COMMAND, multi=True): pass`

Comment: Try to set [`connection.autocommit=True`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-autocommit.html) (or `mysql.connector.connect(..., autocommit=True)` before running the loop.